# Conditions in XSD for validating XML

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

Does XML need to be strictly validated against XSD? How to validate condition based XML in XSD?

I have a scenario where I need to validate a condition. After doing some research I found that XSD 1.0 won't do condition based verification.

Example: based on an attribute 'Y' or 'N', I have to display different elements.

Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: You can ask this question on other stack sites (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XML does not have to be validated against XSD.

XSD 1.0 is not capable of enforcing arbitrary constraints on your data. If you have constraints that cannot be enforced using XSD 1.0, you have a number of choices: redesign the XML, move to XSD 1.1, validate it using a different technology (including the option of writing your own custom validator, say in XSLT), or not validating it at all.

Comment: So, It should be fine if basic validation of xml structure is done against xsd and then programmatically validate the conditional elements. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, that's one approach.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following design:  inside our `A` element, we have a `frob` attribute with the value 'Y' or the value 'N'.  If `frob='Y'`, then `A` must contain `B`, `C`, and zero or more occurrences of `D`; if `frob='N'`, then the contents of `A` are `X`, `Y`, `Z`.  As you say, XSD 1.0 cannot enforce the consistency of the `frob` attribute with the contents of `A`.

Now consider the following design:  the `A` element contains either `B` and `C` followed by zero or more occurrences of `D`, or else `X`, `Y`, and `Z` in that order.  XSD 1.0 can express this design very simply.

For every XML instance correct against the first design, there is a corresponding instance which is correct against the second design, and vice versa.  In other words, the two designs contain exactly the same information.

Under these circumstances, my suggestion would be to ask yourself why you want the redundant `frob` attribute, when it conveys no useful information not already conveyed by the content of `A`.

Comment: I am totally fine if I don't use frob attribute. Can you please provide xml schema for the second suggested design?

Comment: Per your saying we can build up an xsd for the below xml. Please let me know.<A>
<B></B>
<C></C>
<D></D>
</A>


<A>
<X></X>
<Y></Y>
<Z></Z>
</A>

Comment: I am able to figure out the xsd for the above representation using groups. Lets say if I would like the following scenario A - BCD or A -BXYZ. Basically I want B to be appeared in both.

Comment: A little addition to the above. A - B(with only value Y)CD or A -B(with only value N)XYZ